# How to pay for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, payment

It seems that I can't find the way how I'll be charged for AWS. I know about pay-for-what-you-use and hourly model, but I'm looking for another thing:

Will AWS withdraw money from my card during every hour until services are running, or I'll get a bill on the 1st or the last day of a month? How does this very moment work - can anybody explain it to me in details, please?

Answer (score 4):

They will generate monthly bill which you need to pay. You also have flexibility to put it as auto-pay; so that money is automatically debited from your account.
Bill gets generated on 1st of every month.